# QGIS web client only loads background layers and shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

The QGIS web client only loads the background layers in the helloworld map.
In the natural earth I only get the shaded relief.

I open the example project in QGIS Desktop and it works fine. Then I added a shapefile and now the web client shows the background layers and the shapefile but not the data from the helloworld.db

I tried to install QGIS server by following the tutorials of the following links http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial 
and
http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/

I think the web-client is installed correctly but something is wrong with the server.

Has anybody some idea?

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is related to different projections of your source data. Try to make sure:

1. Your project coordinate system is set
2. All your layers have their projections (coordinate system) defined and it's correct

QGIS should be able to overlay one layer over another automagicaly

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem. the helloworld map is EPSG: 4857. al layers inside have this and the project-file too. I only can see the shp file in the Web Client and when i want to add the project as wmts layer over the local server in OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin